# В чем преимущество int[] перед vector<int> или array<int>

Tags: c++

Смотрю разный доступный код по C++ и много где массивы представляют в виде int p[3], например. Соответственно возник вопрос: это просто привычка из C/C# или действительно есть какая-то выгода с этого?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::vector` - это массив не только run-time *начального* размера, но еще и *изменяемого на лету* размера. Это заметно более "тяжелая" и дорогая структура данных, не являющаяся прямым аналогом обычного голого С-массива. Бездумно применять `std::vector` в качестве прямой замены обычного массива - плохая идея.

Что же касается `std::array`, то это прямой аналог С-массива, который к тому же является *копируемым* (в отличие от С-массива), т.е. передаваемым и возвращаемым по значению, присваиваемым и т.д. Свойство копируемости как раз и будет его основным преимуществом над голым С-массивом.

Также, `std::array` позволяет вам создавать массивы размера `0`. В случае С-массивов такое возможно только при создании массива через `new []`.

Иногда в качестве преимущества `std::array` также называют унифицированность его интерфейса со стандартными контейнерами. Однако при необходимости такая унификация вполне достижима и для С-массивов, если алгоритмы реализуются в терминах функций `std::begin`, `std::size` и т.п.

В каких-то редких контекстах некопируемость голого массива и его манера превращаться в указатель могут быть полезными (например, при реализации `<stdarg.h>`), но такие контексты редки и экзотичны. В современном C++ коде, если вам нужен массив фиксированного размера, как правило нет никаких причин избегать использования `std::array`.

Разумеется отдельной темой будет совместимость с C-интерфейсами, где многие C++-структуры становятся неприменимыми. Но это само собой разумеется.

Comment: Неболльшое уточнение про популярность C-массиов. std::array появился в стандарте только в 2011 году. По нему просто мало книг.

Answer (score 2):

В большинстве случаев скорее в силу привычки, но иногда в этом есть смысл. Например, строковые константы определяются как

```
const char MyString[] = "My const string";
```

Не представляю себе человека, который в здравом уме взялся бы это делать через `array<char>`. Или, скажем опять же, константа

```
static const int arrInt[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

выглядит проще и понятнее. Да и вообще константные массивы как-то странно делать классами, там просто нет нужды в возможностях класса.

Иногда и не для константы класс будет излишним и проще сделать традиционным массивом. Но это все надо смотреть для конкретного случая. А в общем случае, надо действительно стараться использовать контейнеры STL.

Comment: `std::array` является `constexpr` классом, он должен нормально хранить константные массивы.

Comment: @Ariox, да, вы правы.

Comment: Строковые константы можно определять как `auto const MyString{"My const string"};` или используя специальный класс `std::string_view`

Comment: @VTT, можно, но нужно ли? Дело вкуса, конечно.

Comment: @freim Да, нужно. Это не дело вкуса.

Comment: В c++17 `std::array` и со строками можно нормально использовать: 
`constexpr std::array v{"321"}`.  Ну и `std::string_view` действительно нужен для константных строк - например, из `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` можно получить кусок, отвечающий за тип шаблонного аргумента функции, что позволяет получить имя типа во время компиляции - при этом не нужно создавать новую строку, достаточно фрагмента исходной.

Comment: @Ariox, и что, часто вам нужно получать кусок, отвечающий за тип шаблонного аргумента функции? Понятно, что можно придумать массу ситуаций, где строковую константу нужно представить именно так, но в большинстве случаев это просто усложнит программу и сделает ее менее наглядной, не добавив абсолютно никаких преимуществ.

Answer (score 1):

`std::array<T, N>` эквивалентен `T[N]` в большинстве случаев, и имеет лучший интерфейс. Но могут возникнуть сложности, если нужно совместить двумерный массив `T[N][M]` с двумерным `std::array`. По большему счету вариант `T[N]` используется или по привычке, или из-за меньшей многословности - полноценный интерфейс `std::array` нужен не всегда, а  вариант `T[N]` явно короче, особенно в случае двумерных массивов. Также иногда компилятор генерирует разный код для этих вариантов, но нельзя сказать, какой из них лучше.

При передаче в качестве аргумента функции или в качестве возвращаемого значения `std::array<T, N>` по удобству выигрывает однозначно.

`std::vector` же является динамическим массивом, и его выбор обусловлен либо необходимостью динамического массива, либо нежеланием заморачиваться с вычислением размера времени компиляции. В частности, это может использоваться для реализации [pimpl](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl), когда для какого-то модуля количество элементов в возвращаемом значении известно во время компиляции, но не сообщается пользователям, чтобы при изменении реализации библиотеки не нужно было перекомпоновать её пользователей.

Answer (score -2):

Есть у массива int p[3] одно неоспоримое преимущество - скорость создания.

Например, есть две функции:

```
void fun1(){
int p[3]= {1,2,3};
//some action
}

void fun2(){
std::vector<int> p= {1,2,3};
//some action
}
```

Функция fun1 будет выполнятся на порядки быстрее, так как массив "p" создается на стеке, а не в куче. Если fun1 используется в глубине многих циклов, то разница в быстродействии может быть весьма значительной.

```
for(;;){
for(;;){
for(;;){
for(;;){
for(;;){
for(;;){

fun1();
//some action

}
}
}
}
}
}
```

> Сравнение скорости создания массива фиксированного размера и массива
>   динамического размера некорректно.

Как раз топик стартер спрашивает:

> В чем преимущество int[] перед vector или array

Скорость создания массива фиксированного размера как раз и является преимуществом этого массива по сравнению с массивом динамического размера.

Ну и конечно ползать по динамическому массиву в общем случае медленнее, чем по массиву фиксированного размера. Можно даже померить на сколько медленнее, но это уж пусть сам топик стартер делает.

Comment: По-моему. вы ошибаетесь насчёт `std::array` - он создаётся на стеке (конечно, если сам класс создан на стеке и если не использовать явно `new`).

Comment: `std::array` содержит массив в качестве поля и никогда не использует выделение памяти на куче. Как следствие, его можно инициализировать посредством aggregate initialization (аналогично обычному массиву) и среди параметров шаблона отсутствует аллокатор. Сравнение скорости создания массива фиксированного размера и массива динамического размера некорректно.